# Android Recycler View with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use a recycler view inside a fragment and am using firebase to get data from the database. The problem is none of my recycler view methods such as onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder, getItemCount are being called when I'm setting the adapter. This I can confirm by running the app in debugger mode. 
My fragment:

public class Ongoing extends Fragment {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProjectAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<ProjectModel> project ;

String[] project_name = new String[3];
String[] project_desc = new String[3];

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_projects);
        project = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("projects");

        ref.child("ongoing").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                int i = 0;
                for(DataSnapshot dsp: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //System.out.println(dsp.child("name").getValue());
                    //System.out.println(dsp.child("description").getValue());
                    //ProjectModel p = new ProjectModel(dsp.child("name").getValue().toString(),dsp.child("description").getValue().toString());
                    //project.add(i,p);
                    project_name[i]= dsp.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    project_desc[i]= dsp.child("description").getValue().toString();
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println(project_name);
                System.out.println(project_desc);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        adapter = new ProjectAdapter(project_name, project_desc,getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        return v;

    }
```

}

My RecyclerView adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.adg.adgofficial.R;

public class ProjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ProjectViewHolder>{

    String[] project_name,project_desc;
    //ArrayList<ProjectModel> project;
    Context context;

    public ProjectAdapter( String[] project_name,String[] project_desc ,Context context) {

        this.project_name = project_name;
        this.project_desc = project_desc;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ProjectViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.projects_element,parent,false);
        return new ProjectViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProjectViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(project_name[position]);
        holder.desc.setText(project_desc[position]);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public static class ProjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title, desc;

        public ProjectViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proj_element_title);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proj_element_desc);
        }
    }
}
```

This issue has been troubling me for weeks and I can't seem to find a solution to it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after for-loop inside your `onDataChange()`

Comment: koceeng I tried doing that but it still didn't help. The Recycler view is still empty.

Comment: Did `System.out.println(project_name);` show any value?

Comment: Yes it is giving the string values of the data recieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ArrayList<String> project_name = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String>  project_desc = new ArrayList<>();


             ref.child("ongoing").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        for(DataSnapshot dsp: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

   ProjectModel p = dsp.getValue(ProjectModel.class);  
                            project_name.add(p.getproject_name);   
                            project_desc.add(p.getproject_desc);

                        }
                        System.out.println(project_name);
                        System.out.println(project_desc);
         adapter = new ProjectAdapter(project_name, project_desc,getActivity());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: @Kronos Did  System.out.println(project_name); show any value?

Comment: Yes it gave the string values of the data recieved.

Comment: I tried the you're suggested answer and yet it's not working. Its still giving a blank fragment. This is what i changed in the for loop datasnapshot:                               ProjectModel p = new ProjectModel(dsp.child("name").getValue().toString(),dsp.child("description").getValue().toString());
                                     project.add(i,p);

Comment: @Kronos are you not using fire base java object class.it  having getter/setter properties.

Comment: No, I'm using my own custom java model class with its own getter and setter.